# Padding string placeholder after bracket in python logging

Tags: python, string, formatting

I currently have my logging string in Python set up like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    format='[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)-5s] %(message)s',
    level=logging.DEBUG
)
```

Which produces something like that:

```
[2018-06-15 10:54:15,021] [DEBUG] debug
[2018-06-15 10:54:15,022] [INFO ] info
[2018-06-15 10:54:15,022] [ERROR] error
```

So the padding for the levelname occurs *inside* the square brackets.  Instead, I would like to have the padding *outside* the bracket, so it looks like this:

```
[2018-06-15 10:54:15,021] [DEBUG] debug
[2018-06-15 10:54:15,022] [INFO]  info
[2018-06-15 10:54:15,022] [ERROR] error
```

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a syntax for putting extra characters (like the []) between '%' and 's', nor can I pad the format string *before* passing it to basicConfig(). Is there a way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 3):

OK I found a solution that involves customizing the LogRecordFactory.  Here it is for reference:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    format='[%(asctime)s] %(levelname_brackets)-7s %(message)s',
    level=logging.DEBUG
)

old_factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()
def record_factory(*args, **kwargs):
    record = old_factory(*args, **kwargs)
    record.levelname_brackets = '[{}]'.format(record.levelname)
    return record
logging.setLogRecordFactory(record_factory)
```

I'd be interested though if there's a simpler way.